# If update the opty field needs to be create new task

Tags: apex, trigger

Whenever an update the Opportunity fields create a new brand task along with Opportunity name. For that we have written a trigger working as expected.

But once create a task if we update the description field it should create a new task not overriding the existing task.

Every time Step(OpportunityField) or Description(OpportunityField) changes, a new task should be created

Example: `Step = 'Legal'`, `Description = 'test'`

If I again select `Step = 'Legal'` and `Description = 'test1234'` a new task should be created. Currently its updating test to 'test1234'.

Please Find my below trigger and let us know where we made the mistakes.

```
Trigger Task on Opportunity(after insert,after update){
    Set<Id> opIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    List<Opportunity> Opps = Trigger.new;
    List<Opportunity> taskOps = [Select Id,Steps__c,Description__c from Opportunity where Id in :opIds];

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for (Opportunity Opp: Opps){
            Task t = new Task();
            t.WhatId = opp.Id;
            t.Subject = 'Help' + ': ' +opp.Steps__c + ': '  + opp.Name; 
            t.Description = opp.Description__c;  
            t.ActivityDate = System.Today()+7;     
            taskList.add(t);
        }
    }

    //Update 
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        Map<Id,Opportunity> oldOppMap = Trigger.oldmap;
        for (Opportunity Opp: Opps){
        // description got changed
            if(Opp.Steps__c != oldOppMap.get(opp.Id).Steps__c ){
                Task t = new Task();
                t.WhatId = opp.Id;       
                t.Subject = 'Help' + ': ' +opp.Steps__c + ': '  + opp.Name; 
                t.Description = opp.Description__c;  
                t.ActivityDate = System.Today()+7;           
                taskList.add(t);
            }
        }
    }

    insert taskList;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your comment says `description got changed`, but you are comparing `Steps__c`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian: Yes,That is one of the single picklist Lov

Answer (score 2):

This situation is the perfect use case for [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector). It's also a good time to:

- Learn how to implement a `Service Layer` <sup>[[1](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Service_Layer)]</sup>
- Understand the `Handler Pattern` <sup>[[2](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)]</sup> and find an implementation that suits you.
- Learn how to properly handle errors <sup>[[3](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling)]</sup>

With Selector, the service layer is fairly simple:

```
public with sharing class OpportunityServices
{
    public static Select.Filter hasStepChanged()
    {
        return Select.Field.hasChanged(Opportunity.Steps__c);
    }
    public static void createTasks()
    {
        // move current implementation here
        // add try/catch
    }
}
```

Then your handler pattern can look something like:

```
public with sharing class OpportunityTriggerHandler
{
    @TestVisible static Boolean bypassTrigger = false;

    final List<Opportunity> newRecords;
    final Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap;
    public NoteTriggerHandler(List<Opportunity> newRecords, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap)
    {
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }

    public void afterInsert()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;

        OpportunityServices.createTasks(newRecords);
    }

    public void afterUpdate()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;

        OpportunityServices.createTasks(
            OpportunityServices.hasStepChanged().filter(newRecords, oldMap)
        );
    }
}
```

Then your trigger simply needs to implement the handler:

```
trigger Opportunity on Opportunity (after insert, after update)
{
    OpportunityTriggerHandler handle = new OpportunityTriggerHandler(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
    if (trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert) handle.afterInsert();
        if (trigger.isUpdate) handle.afterUpdate();
    }
}
```

<sup>[[1](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Service_Layer)]</sup> [Apex Enterprise Patterns - Service Layer](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Service_Layer)
<sup>[[2](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)]</sup> [Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)
<sup>[[3](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling)]</sup> [An Introduction to Exception Handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling)

Comment: have you ever had discussions with Andy Fawcett about adding this to the Force.com Enterprise Architecture (fflib) GitHub.  As I understand it, `Select` is primarily to filter sobjects already in memory, not to do SOQL.  And there's nothing like this in `fflib`  - the `fflib_SObjectSelector` and associated `fflib_QueryFactory` class are for SOQL reuse

Comment: @crop No I've never talked to him at all, actually. I'd love to, but he's a bit of a big fish for me! Regardless, I had no role in the creation of this package, I just love it and use it religiously. It's king of SOC.